# FFImage - Very slow loading of User Photos (Xamarin Forms)

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, photo-gallery, ffimageloading

I am trying to display user photos from the local filesystem using FFImage loading.  I display these photos in a "Cached Image" in a FlowListView as shown:

```
<DataTemplate>
<ffimageloading:CachedImage HeightRequest="100" Aspect="AspectFill"
                        DownsampleHeight="20" DownsampleUseDipUnits="false" 
                        Source="{Binding image}"/>
```

As you can see I load the images very small at DownsampleHeight 20.  But on my HTC Android phone FFImage takes around 10 seconds to load a single image in my flowlistview.

These photos are around 2-5 mb.  I'm thinking I could create a downsampled copy of each picture that is 500 kb and then load the higher quality version on

```
ImageService.Instance.LoadUrl(urlToImage).Success(() => ...
```

But was wondering if there was a better way as the user would still need to wait ~10 seconds for the proper image to appear ...

Answer (score 0):

Resize images at the back-end, save the users traffic & memory, do not use DownsampleHeight etc.